# SQLException No suitable driver found for jdbc sql server

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

This is the error I am getting

```
[2018-04-19 21:58:19,651] ERROR Failed to create job for /kafka/salesforce-source.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:102)
[2018-04-19 21:58:19,651] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:113)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://<SERVER_IP>:1433;databaseName=<DATABASE>;user=<USER>;password=<PASSWORD> for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:sqlserver://<SERVER_IP>:1433;databaseName=<DATABASE>;user=<USER>;password=<PASSWORD>
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://<SERVER_IP>:1433;databaseName=<DATABASE>;user=<USER>;password=<PASSWORD> for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:sqlserver://<SERVER_IP>:1433;databaseName=<DATABASE>;user=<USER>;password=<PASSWORD>
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:79)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:66)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:110)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://<SERVER_IP>:1433;databaseName=<DATABASE>;user=<USER>;password=<PASSWORD> for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:sqlserver://<SERVER_IP>:1433;databaseName=<DATABASE>;user=<USER>;password=<PASSWORD>
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://<SERVER_IP>:1433;databaseName=<DATABASE>;user=<USER>;password=<PASSWORD> for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:sqlserver://<SERVER_IP>:1433;databaseName=<DATABASE>;user=<USER>;password=<PASSWORD>
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.maybeAddConfigErrors(AbstractHerder.java:398)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:164)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:107)
```

Schema Config File

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
rest.port=8084
plugin.path=/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/*,/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/kafka-connect-jdbc-4.1.0.jar,/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar
```

Connect Config

```
name=My-source
connector.class=JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=10
batch.max.rows=1000
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://<SERVER_IP>:1433;databaseName=<DATABASE>;user=<USER>;password=<PASSWORD>
query=SELECT * FROM dbo.ORDERS
mode=bulk
topic.prefix=MYTopic
poll.interval.ms=300000
```

`/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc` is in the `plugin.path` and both `kafka-connect-jdbc-4.1.0.jar` and `mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar` are there. I including these paths in `CLASSPATH` also but it didn't make a difference

Comment: Can you try just `plugin.path=/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc`? You don't need to list all the other file paths.

Comment: I changed it to plugin.path=/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc
I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you restart the Java process? It won't be picked up after the fact

Comment: Restart the Java process? Not sure what that is, I only ran below line
sudo ./connect-standalone /kafka/salesforce-schema.properties /kafka/salesforce-source.properties

Comment: Kafka is a Java application.... But that command should be fine

Comment: What else do you suggest I do?

Comment: I think your JDBC URL is wrong. Try  `jdbc:sqlserver`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017#making-a-simple-connection-to-a-database

Comment: I used same jdbc url and jar file and the code works in my windows box. I can't see anything wrong with the url.

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
import java.sql.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
String conurl = "jdbc:sqlserver://<SERVER_IP>;databaseName=<DATABASE>;user=<USER>;password=<PASSWORD>";

Connection con;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(conurl);

String SQL = "...";
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
}
}

Comment: Oops, I don't know why I thought that error message said `jdbc:mssql`. As [**here**](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/) it says `share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc` is where to place the JAR. And `plugin.path` only needs to be `/confluent-4.1.0/share/java`, realistically. Don't need to limit it only to the JDBC connector classpath.

Comment: Awesome, it seem to work now. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Moving comment to an answer</sup>

As per [the Kafka Connect Blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/)

1. JDBC JARs go into `share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc` folder directly. But I've noticed they can also go into a subdirectory
2. As per other issues I've seen with the `plugin.path` explanations, just setting it to the absolute path of the `share/java` folder of the Confluent installation should be enough.

Also, the `connect-standalone` script should automatically add all `kafka-connect-*/*` files to the classpath, so you may not need to set `plugin.path` at all, but the default behavior to load all connectors is `share/java`, as mentioned.

If you can read bash, here's the script logic

```
# Classpath addition for any Kafka Connect connectors
for library in $java_base_dir/kafka-connect-*; do
  classpath_prefix="$CLASSPATH:"
  if [ "x$CLASSPATH" = "x" ]; then
    classpath_prefix=""
  fi
  CLASSPATH="$classpath_prefix$library/*"
done
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. But in my case after copying the jar into plugin folder, the error had existed. After restarting (rerunning) the connector, it now works great.

Comment: Yes. JARs only get loaded when the JVM starts fresh. Was this not clear in the documentation? If so, could you please send feedback on the Kafka Connect JDBC pages on the Confluent site?

Comment: I haven't read Kafka Connect JDBC pages completely. I found it just by restarting my worker.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same error and after changing the plugin path from  **/kafka-connect-jdbc-4.0.0-package/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc**, to 
**/kafka-connect-jdbc-4.0.0-package/share**, it worked.

This is applicable for both postgres and sql server connection.